# Populating ComboBox Items with members from a dynamic database, C#

Tags: c#, database, linq, combobox

My database, db, has as a primary key 'Artist' with foreign key 'CdTitle', in one form a user can enter information to add to the database, in another form, I have a combobox that I want to populate with the names of the artist in the database, primarily 'Artist.Names' I've tried using a LINQ to traverse the database and put the results of the query into the combobox but it's not working like i thought.

the code I have is :

```
var ArtistNames = 
    from name in formByArtist.db.Artists    
    select name.Name;

foreach (var element in ArtistNames)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(element.ToString());                               
}
```

Comment: What's not working about it? The code seems correct...

Comment: @dahlbyk: it is incorrect - nothing has executed and ArtistNames is null (I believe)...Any how, the linq statement must be executed with either `.ToList()`; `First()`; `FirstOrDefault()`, etc.

Comment: The query will be executed immediately by the `foreach`. If you want to use `DataSource`, you are correct that you need `ToList()` or something.

Comment: I don't see any problem in the above code. The problem might be in a different part of the source. You should be more descriptive about what's not working. Any exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Suposing your Artist have a Name and an Id, you can do this:

```
comboBox1.DataValueField = "Id";
comboBox1.DataTextField = "Name";

comboBox1.DataSource = formByArtist.db.Artists;
comboBox1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't think the `.DataBind()` is necessary. But +1, this is the method I use and I think it's the cleanest. :)

Comment: @IAbstract: Assuming db.Artists is an ObjectSet<T> or IQueryable<T> you are **completely** incorrect. I have this exact same code running and it works fine.

Comment: @Sergio: I see the difference - nice shortcut ;). Are you able to filter the contents of the `ComboBox`? I'm partial to the linq execution. My guess is then that the CLR is generating the very linq equivalent that I would be coding anyway.

Comment: @IAbstract I filter the collection before setting it to a datasource.

Comment: @IAbstract: By binding the collection to the combo box, the linq statement becomes completely useless. It was just to retrieve the names.

Comment: @Sergio: I don't believe Andre's code is filtering anything. It lookas like the equivalent of a "SELECT Name, Id FROM tbl_Artists" and that's it.

Comment: @IAbstract: He wants a list of all the artists in his database. OP doesn't want to filter anything.

Comment: @Sergio: DataBind is necessary in ASP.net but it works without in WinForms.

Comment: @IAbstract, I don't see what's your point here. There's no filter in this solution, because it's not necessary. If it was necessary, then we could add a linq here, just like your solution does. But the linq in your solution is not really filtering anything.

Comment: @Andre: I think your solution works, but isn't necessarily the most understandable. The OP suggested that the query is performed by linq. Otherwise, I am simply asking questions to gain a better understanding of this shortcut and it's limitations. :)

Comment: Ok, then... I believe I was still thinking on your first answer, where you seemed to me that your were convinced that the query must be executed. Maybe because I learned this way, I think this solution is understandable, and very readable. Ideal when you don't have to filter anything, cases where your solution is fits better.

Answer (score 1):

From your existing sample, modify as follows:

```
var ArtistNames = 
    (from name in formByArtist.db.Artists    
     select name.Name)
    .ToList();

comboBox1.DataSource = ArtistNames;
```